# How to avoid intermediate screen while calling lightning component

Tags: lightning

I am calling lightning component inside the quick action button.
on click of quick action button all my lightning component will wrk.But i dont want the intermediate screen to pop up on click of quick action button.i need to invoke my lightning component directly with out intermediate screen.Can we control the standard page from popping up.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your lightning component has UI ? wont that UI load in quick action?

Comment: UI is there.On UI also starting has one button on click of that button again one more pop up will come so it will be repeated.

Comment: You are opening a popup in your lightning component? If yes, you can write your UI without any popup. One default is from quick action button!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about Lightning action button so as I know there is no way to avoid this pop-up. Basically this pop-up is supposed to contain your lightning component.

In case if your LC has no UI you can place spinner inside it and close pop-up in controller:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader"> 
  <aura:handler name="init"  value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>

  <div>
    <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading" size="medium"/>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

.

```
({
  init: function(cmp, evt, hlp) {
    $A.get('e.force:closeQuickAction').fire();
  }
})
```

.

```
.THIS .slds-spinner_container {
  position: inherit;
}
```